# Can I enable/disable parts of a query using prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT foo, bar FROM mytable WHERE foo=:foo AND userid=:userid;
```

I want to loose the `AND userid=:userid` part for 'admin' class users (they get to see the `foo`s of all users).

Is there a way to do that using PDO prepared statements? Or am I to use string concatenation to create two different queries? I was thinking of using some kind of `LIKE` structure also, but it feels a little lumpy.

Comment: @zerkms: thanks. I am using `sprintf` now to build them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do this.

You can have two prepared statements and use logic to select between them though.

```
$queryWithUser = $pdo -> prepare ('SELECT foo, bar FROM mytable WHERE foo=:foo AND userid=:userid;');
$queryWithoutUser = $pdo -> prepare ('SELECT foo, bar FROM mytable WHERE foo=:foo;');

$result = $doQueryWithUser?
    $queryWithUser -> execute (array ('foo' => 123, 'userid' => 456)):
    $queryWithoutUser -> execute (array ('userid' => 456));
```

Or you can generate the prepared statement you need at a particular time on demand.

```
$queryString = 'SELECT foo, bar FROM mytable WHERE foo=:foo';
if ($doQueryWithUser) {
    $queryString .= ' AND userid=:userid';
}
$query = $pdo -> prepare ($queryString . ';');
```